# Theresa May and Jeremy Corbyn's viewpoint on Same-sex marriage

Tags: united-kingdom, jeremy-corbyn

What is  Theresa May and Jeremy Corbyn's opinion on Same-sex marriage?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Theresa May's position

She did [pledge support for same-sex marriage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theresa_May#Same-sex_marriage) in May 2012 when she was Home Secretary:

> Theresa May, the Conservative home secretary, **has pledged her personal support for gay marriage**, becoming the most senior politician yet to take part in a cross-party video campaign supporting a change to the law.
>
> The video, in which May **says she believes that "marriage should be for everyone"**, was released on the day it emerged that David Cameron has decided to give his MPs a free vote on the government's plans to legalise gay marriage, thereby avoiding a showdown with Conservative colleagues, including some ministers, strongly opposed to the idea.
>
> *(emphasis mine)*
>
> <sup>Source: https://www.theguardian.com/world/2012/may/24/theresa-may-video-gay-marriage</sup>

---

### Jeremy Corbyn's position

He [has pledged support for LGBT rights](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Political_positions_of_Jeremy_Corbyn#LGBT_issues) since being a London councillor in the 1970s:

> As Labour leader and a future Prime Minister I **would be committed to standing up for LGBT communities**, both at home and abroad. It's a basic issue of principle: everyone has the right be treated equally and with respect.
>
> [ ... ]
>
> I have **always supported LGBT rights and it's encouraging to consider how attitudes have changed**. It shows that we can win arguments, we can change opinions and we can make the world a better place - though there are many challenges and still a long way to go. Those of us who backed LGBT rights in the 1980s were denounced as 'loony left' but now those who oppose LGBT equality are an increasingly derided minority.
>
> *(emphasis mine)*
>
> <sup>Source: http://www.lgbtlabour.org.uk/jeremy_corbyn</sup>

Comment: Theresa May has historically voted against Gay Rights, and held anti-gay rights positions in the past - https://www.vice.com/en_uk/article/d38mww/we-discovered-an-old-interview-with-theresa-may-where-she-talks-about-her-views-on-promoting-homosexuality - although she has more recently stated that these views were "a mistake" - https://www.politico.eu/article/theresa-may-tories-gay-rights/ - whereas Jeremy Corybyn has been a consistent supporter of LGBT rights.