# What are Theresa May's views on LGBTQ+ rights?

Tags: united-kingdom, lgbt+, theresa-may

Written in [Theresa May says not to worry about DUP views on ‘LGB…what’s the rest of it?’](http://metro.co.uk/2017/06/12/theresa-may-says-not-to-worry-about-dup-views-on-lgb-whats-the-rest-of-it-6704187/#ixzz4jt99qLkf):

> The Prime Minister was meeting the 1922 Committee of backbenchers
>   today amid controversy over the government’s discussions with the
>   Democratic Unionist Party of Ulster.
>
> A Tory MP is said to have told HuffPo editor Paul Waugh that the PM
>   had made the apparently flippant comment about LGBT concerns in the
>   meeting today.

This to me would show either a lack of knowledge about the cause or a lack of compassion, which then made me wonder:

---

What are Theresa May's personal/political views on LGBTQ+ rights?

**Note**:

- [LGBTQ](https://www.washingtonpost.com/news/arts-and-entertainment/wp/2014/05/23/civilities-what-does-the-acronym-lgbtq-stand-for/) stands for Lesbian, Gay, Bisexual, Transgender, Queer
- There is also a full version of the acronym such as [LGBTQQIAAP](https://decahedronofq.wordpress.com/what-is-lgbtqqiaap/)
  which stands for Lesbian, Gay, Bisexual, Transgender, Queer,
  Questioning, Intersex, Asexual, Allies and Pansexual (but it normally stops at LGBTQ as the others are laying under the umbrella of Queer.)

Comment: related: https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/18340/theresa-may-and-jeremy-corbyns-viewpoint-on-same-sex-marriage

Comment: Could you explain what the letters stand for so everyone can understand what the question is about?

Comment: @gnasher729 edited the question to align with your comment.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Theresa May's stance on LGBTQ has changed over the years. However, since the Conservative leadership election, she has endorsed LGBT rights as seen from [the statement she gave to the Conservative Party group LGBTory](https://www.lgbtconservatives.org.uk/news/candidates-prime-minister-express-their-views-lgbt-issues).

> "When I launched my campaign for the leadership I set out my belief in building a country that works for everyone.  Central to that vision is a commitment to equality, and I will always stand up for the rights of LGBT people.
>
> I supported Civil Partnerships in 2004, and was proud to sponsor the legislation that introduced full marriage equality in 2013 because I believe marriage should be for everyone, regardless of their sexual orientation.  I didn’t believe the State should perpetuate discrimination and prejudice against LGBT people. That's why equal marriage was a hugely significant social reform.  And it also made a powerful and important statement that as a country we value and respect everyone.
>
> For me, equality is about fairness.  It is simply wrong for anyone to face discrimination or abuse because of who they are or who they love.  A Conservative Government under my leadership would be unequivocally committed to supporting LGBT people, and continuing the vital task of tackling hate crime, homophobia and transphobia – both in the UK and around the world.
>
> I firmly believe in an open, inclusive, One Nation agenda of social reform which will change our country for the better.  That is what I would offer as Prime Minister."

---

As for her voting record, it's mixed as she voted against same-sex adoption in 2002 and mostly against LGBTQ rights before 2010. However, her attitude towards it seem to have softened afterwards and she voted in favour of same-sex adoption in 2014.

She has also acknowledged her change in position, [telling Question Time](http://www.independent.co.uk/news/uk/politics/theresa-may-lgbt-rights-gay-commons-vote-same-sex-marriage-gay-adoption-tim-farron-a7702326.html) that:

> "I have changed my view. If those votes were taken today, I would take a different vote."
>
> "On gay adoption I have changed my mind… because I have been persuaded that when you are looking at the future for a child, I think it’s better for a child who is perhaps in an institutional environment, if they have an opportunity of being in a stable, family environment – be that a heterosexual couple or a gay couple."

---

However, it's worth noting that she might have followed the party’s position on equal rights since the Conservatives took power after forming a coalition in 2010. Her predecessor David Cameron also mentioned before stepping down that having equal marriage will "continue to be the case" in the future.

> "On equal marriage, I’m extremely proud of it and so many people have taken advantage of it," the Prime Minister said.
>
> "I think there’s now an enormous parliamentary majority for equal marriage so I’m confident that it will continue to be the case."

[This article by The Independent](http://www.independent.co.uk/news/uk/politics/theresa-may-lgbt-rights-gay-commons-vote-same-sex-marriage-gay-adoption-tim-farron-a7702326.html) is quite comprehensive and details Theresa May's stance on equal rights and her voting record throughout her political career.

Comment: Note that 2010 was when a Coalition Conservative government replaced a Labour one, so it's possible this represents party loyalties rather than personal opinion.

Comment: @origimbo Possibly, and I have updated my answer to reflect that.